Integral of periodic function times derivative of periodic function
I have a periodic function $f(x)$ over $[0,L]$ (this is from a physics scenario, so everything is well-behaved, differentiable, etc.). I also have a function g(f(x)) which is clearly also periodic.
I'm interested in the integral
$$
\int_0^L g(f) \partial_x\ln(f) \, \mathrm{d} x.
$$
Using integration by parts we can turn this into:
$$
[g \cdot \ln(f)]_0^L - \int_0^L \partial_x g(f) \ln(f) \, \mathrm{d} x.
$$
The boundary terms vanish, and then using substitution with $\mathrm{d}f = \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x} \mathrm{d}x$ this gives us:
$$
\int_{x=0}^{x=L} \partial_f g(f) \frac{\mathrm{d} f}{\mathrm{d}x} \ln(f) \frac{1}{\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}} \mathrm{d} f = \int_{f(x=0)}^{f(x=L)} \partial_f g(f) \ln(f) df.
$$
And since $f$ is periodic, $f(0)=f(L)$ and so the integral vanishes.
Is this reasoning correct?
I would like this integral to be zero but I'm not convinced by this reasoning.
For example, if $g(x)$ is not a function of $f$ this is clearly not true (e.g. if $g$ is sharply peaked) but I can't see where the reasoning would change.
Any help much appreciated!

You seem to believe that the integral of a periodic function over a period vanishes. This is not true. Consider $f(x) = 1$, which is clearly periodic with period $a$ (for any real $a$), but the integral $\int_r^{r+a}f(t)dt$ will only vanish for $a=0$.

Ok, I understand that -- I had previously realised that you need the integrand to be the /derivative/ of a periodic function to give 0 over the period. The limits on the final integral however aren't values of x, they're values of f. Maybe I'm missing something obvious but what exactly is wrong here?
